# When ever I open my android studio it show this type of message in my "Event log" option

Tags: android, android-studio

```
        EmptyThrowable
        Invalid stub element type in index:
        file: file://D:/needed/sdk/sources/android-23/android/support/v7/internal/app/ToolbarActionBar.java
        psiElement: PsiImportStatement
        requiredClass: interface com.intellij.psi.PsiClass
        actualClass: class com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiImportStatementImpl
        virtualFile: size:20548; stamp:0; modCount:1454598016731; fileType:JAVA; language:JAVA
        document: size:20548; stamp:0; committed:true; saved:true
        psiFile: size:20548; stamp:0; class:com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiJavaFileImpl; language:JAVA
        stubInfo: created in getStubTree(); with backReference
        indexing info: no data
```

Comment: thats the log which belongs to android studio internal operations..What is your problem here?

Comment: Unless this prevents you from running your app, I'd say it's dismissable. I get various errors in my IDE too that don't mean anything important